# Как правильно изучать исходники ядра linux?

Tags: linux

Всем привет.

Не так давно я заинтересовался одним низкоуровневым вопросом работы ОС, но сходу не смог его разрешить. Мне посоветовали (что в принципе и логично) почитать исходники ядра, чтобы прояснить самому себе, как дело обстоит *на самом деле.* Скачать исходный код ядра убунты не оказалось проблемой, но вот разобраться в нем для меня оказалось довольно проблематично, что и не удивительно. Там столько файлов, и совершенно непонятно, куда копать =(

Короче, мне нужен совет или даже методика, как подходить к изучению исходных кодов ядра, да и чужого исходного кода вообще (хотя я сомневаюсь, что тут какая-то методика вообще может быть), не в привязке конкретно к моей проблеме (я умышленно тут не рассказываю, что именно я хочу узнать), а вообще, в принципе. Я хотел бы для начала хотя бы определиться со структурой папок, понять какие файлы за что отвечают, узнать о каких-то возможно основных файлах исходного кода.

Был бы очень рад ссылкам на полезные ресурсы или какие-нибудь книги по этой тематике!

Answer (score 11):

> Скачать исходный код ядра убунты не оказалось проблемой, но вот разобраться в нем для меня оказалось довольно проблематично, что и не удивительно. Там столько файлов, и совершенно непонятно, куда копать =(

Для меня, как и возможно для большинства людей,
Был самым простым путь в познании ядра,
Копаясь во всех фичах и настройках,
Мне приходилось собирать его с нуля. Компилить.

Т.е собирать, собирать, собирать, собирать
Ещё раз собирать, потом в него грузиться
Не бутится, опять, беда, опять идти и компилять.
Глядеть в dmesg, искать, вникать,
Всё бросить и снова 30-50 минут сидеть и компилить.

Зимою можно так согреть ладони,
Когда сквозняк и стужа рвутся сквозь занавески штор,
Уже пройдя двойные стёкла стеклопакетов, сквозь стены...
На ноутбуке ты набираешь `make CONFIG`.

Зачем брать убунтушное,
Возьмите дефолтное, прямо на www.kernel.org,
Там документация, примерно тут: www.kernel.org/doc

---

В самом начале,на заре,
ядро являло из себя
лишь базовый функционал,
И постоянно дописывалось мудрым Торвальдсом.

Все разбирались с ядром по ходу выполнения каких-то маленьких задач.
К примеру, для запуска какой-нибудь прекрасной демонюки
Необходимо было `патчить ядро`.
Брались исходники, вносился патч и собиралось *кастомное ядро*.

Сейчас же, большинство необходимых вещей,
Таких как слойчатай файловая система aufs,
И модули прослушивания сетевых интерфейсов,
Всё это уже в  ядре по-умолчанию,
Включается и выключается одной лишь строчкой
В конфигурационном файле сборки ядра.

Но Вы можете повторить весь этот путь
Найти себе интересным такой проект как grsecurity.net

Спомощью этого патча можно создать пули-не-пробиваемый сервант
С миллионом следящих, логгирующих элементов.
Запрещать всё, что только можно запрещать.
К слову сказать, достаточно нетривиальной
Является задача запуска X-сервера
С максимально-возможным "включеным" grsecurity-патчем.

В процессе сборки кастомного пули-не-пробиваемого ядра
И попытки загрузиться с него,
У Вас появится некоторое представление об иерархии всех флагов.
Вы сможете понять, что 90% ядра - ни что иное как модули
Конкретно взятых железяк, карт сетевых и звуковых
И всякого подобного добра.

А те, оставшиеся 10% - это и есть само Ядро,
Core of Kernel, если можно так сказать.
Сетевая, дисковая подсистемы,
Шедулер - Планировщик задач,
Всякие фичи, хуки, хаки, баги...

Хотя, сколько я ни копался во всём этом.
До сих пор, большинство сходится во мнении,
Что лучше документации, чем сам исходный код - НЕТ.
Вероятно, создание этакой "<s>википедии</s>" "ядро-педии"
Поверх кода ядра и поддержание документации в up-to-date состоянии
Это задача многих миллиардов человеко-часов.
Эта задача попросту не подсильна сообществу.
По-этому вход в kernel-hacking до сих пор
Достаточно высок и требует как минимум хорошего знания C/C++.

> Короче, мне нужен совет или даже методика, как подходить к изучению исходных кодов ядра,

Ищите интересный патч,
Вносите...
И компильте, сотни раз...
После 2 тысяч процедур
На Вас снизойдёт озарение.
Так было с каждым.
И будет так всегда.

Faber est suae quisque fortunae

Comment: что ​​​​​​​​это

Comment: @Etki Нет слов, одни эмоции

Comment: @Etki белый стих?

Comment: ядро само себя не с͉̹̣͇к͏͉о̵̲̮м̮̳̙̫п͞и̙ли̮̻͉̳̝͓̮р̡̼̞͇̞̻͖̭уе̴̮̠т̶͈̯

Comment: Собрали ядро и все еще считаете себя не таким как все? Тогда мы идем к Вам!

Comment: Чистейшая поэзия!

Comment: Мне понравилось.

Answer (score 4):

1. Ядро Linux - большая и сложная система, поэтому изучать его целиком крайне трудоемко.
2. Начать всегда стоит с ознакомления с основами, чтобы понять, как система работает в целом. Например, прочитать книгу [Ядро ОС Linux: руководство системного программиста](http://www.npksv.ru/soft/unix/linux_khg/index.php).
3. Просмотреть заметки для начинающих на [kernelnewbies.org](http://kernelnewbies.org/).
4. Найти интересующий модуль ядра (исходя из той задачи, которая стоит).
5. Далее - поиск по коду grep'ом и просмотр его построчно. Иногда помогают IDE, которые строят диаграммы вызовов функций и связи между ними.

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению у меня нет столько времени сколько у поэта (1-ый пост) и любителя книг долгими зимними вечерами (2-ой пост). поэтому подмечу пару очевидных принципов для "атаки сходу".

1. планируем.
   определяем модуль про который будем  по принципу. "я хорошо знаю как работает spi. я видел как он устроен в нескольких разных системах", ну или хотя бы "я один раз писал его сам" - хотя это уже не так эффективно.
2. высаживаемся.
   широким охватом ищем все вхождения слова "spi". среди выдачи ищем о чем то говорящие названия. цель - начать изучения исходника будучи снабженным начальным контекстом. например в названии файла есть название микросхемы которую вы немного знаете или в общих чертах понятно и можно быстро прочитать даташит что она делает.
3. наступление.
   ищем функции с названиями говорящими нам "ты приблизительно знаешь что я делаю, ведь в любом spi идет передача данных от слейва к мастеру" или "у каждого spi есть буфер в который нужно сохранить принятое".
4. постоянный контроль успехов.
   у нас мало ресурсов и времени и сил, если есть хоть какой то намек на то что не понятно всё, уходим на следующий круг и начинаем с пункта 2.
5. когда нашли несколько знакомых функций и видно их связи, дальше думаю понятно что делать - узнавать что там за незнакомые. идти всегда по легкому пути ибо даже он тяжел. тяжелый же, пока, просто не преодолим.

в целом. читали вы книги по линукс или нет сведется все к похожим шагам. и вместо того чтобы выкраивать ценное время на отсев ненужной ЛИЧНО ВАМ воды из даже хорошей книжки, может уже сразу поработать? и еще аргумент против чтения книг. когда у тебя есть задача А, и ты её пытаешься решить решив задачу B сначала, то на слабой и не усвоенной базе B ты можешь это делать сильно долго.

Comment: я сам подобным методом изучаю исходные коды большие, ведь даже название заголовка .h обычно говорит, что там описано...